# Predict a simple sequence with R, support vector machine

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, plot, svm

I am trying to use a support vector machine for predict a sequence of values, for example:

the input 0, 1, 2, 3 will predict 4

For this reason I approached this issue as a regression ML problem in R, here is my code:

```
library("e1071")
x0 <- c(0)
x1 <- c(0, 1)
x2 <- c(0, 1, 2)
x3 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3)
x4 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
x5 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x6 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
x7 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

x = c(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7)
y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

df = data.frame(x, y)
df

svmfit = svm(y ~ ., data = df)
print(svmfit)
```

At the moment I am getting stuck on how to create the input sequences properly and I keep receiving this error:

> Error in data.frame(x, y): arguments imply differing number of rows:
>   36, 8 Traceback:
>
> 1. data.frame(x, y)
> 2. stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s",   .     paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please check your `df <- data.frame(x, y)` the `length(x)` is 8 and that of 'y' is 36, it is not recycling.  May be you need to explicity use `rep`  i.e. `df <-  data.frame(x, y = rep(y, length.out = length(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the unequal length of 'x', 'y' vector (36, 8) and it is not a multiple of the other, so recycling is not happening.  One option is `rep`licate the 'y' vector to make the lengths same as 'x' and then do the `svm`

```
df <- data.frame(x, y = rep(y, length.out = length(x))) 
svmfit = svm(y ~ ., data = df)

svmfit

#Call:
#svm(formula = y ~ ., data = df)


#Parameters:
#   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
# SVM-Kernel:  radial 
#       cost:  1 
#      gamma:  1 
#    epsilon:  0.1 


#Number of Support Vectors:  34
```

Comment: I understand your point, but by doing this I am optaining a y column that repeats over and over all the numbers from 1 to 8. Thus the model will make a wrong prediction.